# How to properly test asynchronous faye server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, bdd, faye, private-pub

I am using the private_pub gem to have real-time functionality in my app.

I feel really guilty, but I have dropped testing this app!

In order to make sure everything works manually, I have to have two browsers open communicating with each other. (Imagine a facebook chat.)

I don't know how to have two browsers open at once in selenium, capybara, or cucumber. I am open to any kind of testing framework or utility.

How do I test with two open browsers? Let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium you can open how much browsers that you want
But you need to save each browser instance in different variable (WebDriver object)
Then do whatever you want with each instance
Be aware that writing and maintaining such tests required a lot of effort (errors, false positive, timing issues, and much more)